# Why is the result of Number.isNaN('abc') false?

Tags: javascript, undefined-behavior

I've looked at the MDN Documentation and other Stack Overflow questions, however was not able to find an exact reasoning for this one. I understand that isNaN tries to parse the values into number, but when I try to run Number.parseInt or Number.parseFloat on 'abc' it gives me 'NaN' but when I actually run the isNaN function it gives me 'false'.

I am aware that there are better ways to check if something is a number or not such as Number.isFinite( ), but in this case I am trying to understand how isNaN is working.

```js
console.log(Number.parseInt('abc'));
console.log(Number.parseFloat('abc'));

console.log(Number.isNaN('abc'));
```

Comment: Because `'abc'`'s type isn't number. *"isNaN tries to parse the values into number"* - no, it doesn't. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN. You may be thinking of the global version https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN.

Comment: Yes, in that case shouldn't isNAN be true instead of false? isNAN stands for is Not a Number right?

Comment: "*I understand that isNaN tries to parse the values into number,*" - you're correct, the global [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function does that. However, you're calling [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) which is a different function that has a different operation. It literally checks if the value you give it ***is*** `NaN`, not whether *it converts* to `NaN`

Comment: No, a string isn't a `Number`, but it also isn't the numerical value `NaN`.

Comment: @Link it stands for *the value* "not a number". Not for *any* value that happens to not be a number.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and answers, it was my bad, I got confused between isNaN and Number.isNaN :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NaN` is a special *number* value. `Number.isNaN` verifies whether the passed in value is equal to `NaN`, because "normal" comparison doesn't work (`NaN == NaN` is `false` by definition).

Unlike some other methods, `Number.isNaN` does *not* perform type conversion. `'abc'` is a *string* value therefore it cannot be `NaN`.

The [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-number.isnan) defines `Number.isNaN` as:

> 1. If Type(*number*) is not Number, return `false`.
> 2. If *number* is `NaN`, return `true`.
> 3. Otherwise, return `false`.

---

Note that there's also the global [`isNaN`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number) function, which behaves differently: If you give it a value that isn't of the number type, it converts it to the number type before doing its check. So `isNaN('abc')` is `true` because if you convert `'abc'` to number using the default string-to-number conversion, you get `NaN`; but `Number.isNaN('abc')` is `false` because it doesn't do that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Not adding anything new here.

Simply trying to make it a bit more clear for beginners.

---

`isNaN(value)` checks if ***value*** is **literally** "**NaN**".

If ***value*** is "**NaN**", `isNaN(value)` returns **true**.

If ***value*** is anything else (eg. **number**, or **string**, or **undefined**, or **null**, or **Infinity**, or **anything else**, `isNaN(value)` returns **false**.

```
//Examples that Return FALSE
//
console.log(20); // value is 20 - is NOT NaN
console.log(isNaN(20)); // false   

console.log('20'); // value is "20" - is NOT NaN
console.log(isNaN('20')); // false


console.log(23 / 0); // is Infinity - Is NOT NaN
console.log(isNaN(23 / 0)); // false


//Examples that Return TRUE
//

console.log(parseInt('X20')); // is NaN
console.log(isNaN(parseInt('X20'))); // true 

console.log(+'20X'); // is NaN
console.log(isNaN(+'20X')); // true 

console.log(Math.sqrt(-1)); // is NaN
console.log(isNaN(Math.sqrt(-1))); // true 

console.log(7 ** NaN); // is NaN
console.log(isNaN(7 ** NaN)); // true 

console.log(0 * Infinity); // is NaN
console.log(isNaN(0 * Infinity)); // true 

console.log('foo' / 30); // is NaN
console.log(isNaN('foo' / 30)); // true `
```

As correctly noted, it's better to use `Number.isFinite(value)` to check if **value** is a number.